# Swift Calendar.current.nextDate timeZone issues

Tags: swift, date, calendar, timezone

I am trying to get a `Date` object for the next occurring future time where the hour in UTC time is 18. However my code doesn't work as expected. I have the following:

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(timeZone: TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT"), hour: 18)
let date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: dateComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)

print(date)
```

The problem is that this results in `2019-02-09 23:00:00 +0000`

The date is for the next occurring time where the hour is 18 in `EST`.

I would have expected, since the the `dateComponents` has the timezone set to UTC and the hour to 18, that the date would be `2019-02-09 18:00:00 +0000`.  Furthermore, changing the timezone seems to have no effect on the `nextDate` found.

Why doesn't the nextDate function respect the timezone set in the `dateComponents` passed to it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the timezone in DateComponents is ignored.
However when you set the timezone in a new calendar you get correct results.

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(hour: 18)
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

let date = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: dateComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)

print(date) // Optional(2020-09-29 18:00:00 +0000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I live in GMT time, and running this in a playground produces the expected result you are looking for. You are setting the time zone of your date component, but I would imagine your own calendar (Calendar.current) is set to EST. You would need to account for the offset in EST vs GMT for your required result

Comment: Does the timezone of the date component have 0 effect on the date returned then?